# How to remove duplicate values from a json array using node js?

Tags: arrays, json, node.js

I have my json Array input like this :-

```
var temp =  [{first: 569, second: "789", third: "458"},  {first: value1, 476: "147", third: "369"},  {first: 100, second: "200", third: "300"},  {first: 100, second: "200", third: "300"},   {first: 100, second: "200", third: "300"}];
```

I want to remove duplicates from this and need an output like :

```
var temp =  [{first: 569, second: "789", third: "458"},  {first: value1, 476: "147", third: "369"},  {first: 100, second: "200", third: "300"}];
```

How can i achieve this ?

Comment: You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Comment: No one will post a question here before researching. I tried lots of things but didn't get what i want thats why i posted here for help ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `array#map` and `JSON.stringify` to create string from object and then use `Set` to get all unique string and then convert back to object using `array#map` and `JSON.parse()`.

Following proposal won't work if the data type isn't JSON.

```js
const temp =  [{first: 569, second: "789", third: "458"},  {first: 476, second : "147", third: "369"},  {first: 100, second: "200", third: "300"},  {first: 100, second: "200", third: "300"},   {first: 100, second: "200", third: "300"}];

const result = [...new Set(temp.map(obj => JSON.stringify(obj)))]
                 .map(str => JSON.parse(str));
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```